# Constant function on the generic fiber $f^{-1}(\eta)$ is contained in the function field $K(U)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $U$ and $V$ be irreducible varieties and $f\colon V\rightarrow U$ be a proper surjective morphism.
Assume, $f^{-1}(\eta)$ is irreducible ($\eta$ is the generic point of $U$).
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}  
 f^{-1}(\eta) @>\displaystyle  >> V\\
 @V \displaystyle \ V V\ @VV
\displaystyle{f} V\\
 \operatorname{Spec}(k(\eta)) @>>   \displaystyle  > U
 \end{CD}
I want to prove

> Let $\phi\in H^{0}(V,\mathcal{O}_{V})$, then $\phi \in K(U)$ ($K(U)$ is the function field of $U$).

Intuitively, $\phi\mid_{f^{-1}(\eta)}$ is constant, so $\phi\in k(\eta)$. But, I don't understand how to prove rigorously.
I think I have to consider flat base change,
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}  
 f^{-1}(\eta)\otimes \overline{k(\eta)} @>>>f^{-1}(\eta) @>\displaystyle  >> V\\
 @V \displaystyle \ V V\ @VV
\displaystyle{f\mid_{f^{-1}(\eta)}} V@VV\displaystyle{f} V\\
 \operatorname{Spec}(\overline{k(\eta)}) @>>> \operatorname{Spec}(k(\eta)) @>>   \displaystyle  > U
 \end{CD}

I'm stuck.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the problem? As you write, $\phi_{|f^{-1}(\eta )}\in H^0(f^{-1}(\eta ),\mathscr{O})=f^*k(\eta )=f^*K(U)$.

Comment: Thanks. You mean since $f^{-1}(\eta)$ is proper irreducible over $k(\eta)$, $f^{*}\colon k(\eta)\rightarrow H^{0}(f^{-1}(\eta),\mathcal{O})$ is an isomorphism ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.